# Regex getting the tags from an <a href= ...> </a> and the likes

Tags: html, regex, href

I've tried the answers I've found in SOF, but none supported here : https://regexr.com
I essentially have an .OPML file with a large number of podcasts and descriptions.
in the following format:

```
<outline text="Software Engineering Daily" type="rss" xmlUrl="http://softwareengineeringdaily.com/feed/podcast/" htmlUrl="http://softwareengineeringdaily.com" />
```

What regex I can use to so I can just get the title and the link:

> Software Engineering Daily
>
> http://softwareengineeringdaily.com/feed/podcast/

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but anyway:
 [`\b(text|xmlUrl)\h*=\h*(["'])((?:(?!\2).)*)\2`](https://regex101.com/r/1vjFdX/1), or if you want to catch the possibility of no `"` or `'` surrounding the attribute values: `\b(text|xmlUrl)\h*=\h*(?:(["'])((?:(?!\2).)*)\2|\S+)`

Comment: You should probably use an html/xml parser instead of regex.

Comment: You could use [`(?:text|xmlUrl)="(.+?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/OGy6PZ/1)

Comment: wow, thanks. you can put it as the answer if you like. Do you recommend a good book, good course (I knew few but I would like to ask for your recommendation)

Comment: For the best book, I can not advise you on that one. But you should check out the first link in the comment from @ctwheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

There are many ways to go about this. The best way is likely using an XML parser. I would definitely read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) that discusses use of regex, especially with XML.

As you can see there are many answers to your question. It also depends on which language you are using since regex engines differ. Some accept backreferences, whilst others do not. I'll post multiple methods below that work in different circumstances/for different regex flavours. You can probably piece together from the multiple regex methods below which parts work best for you.

---

### Code

#### Method 1

This method works in almost any regex flavour (at least the normal ones).

This method only checks against the attribute value opening and closing marks of `"` and doesn't include the possibility for whitespace before or after the `=` symbol. This is the simplest solution to get the values you want.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yLWCdL/1)

```
\b(text|xmlUrl)="[^"]*"
```

Similarly, the following methods add more *value* to the above expression

```
\b(text|xmlUrl)\s*=\s*"[^"]*"          Allows whitespace around =
\b(text|xmlUrl)=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')    Allows for ' to be used as attribute value delimiter
```

As another alternative (following the comments below my answer), if you wanted to grab every attribute *except* specific ones, you can use the following. Note that I use `\w`, which should cover most attributes, but you can just replace this with whatever valid characters you want. `\S` can be used to specify any non-whitespace characters or a set such as `[\w-]` may be used to specify any word or hyphen character. The negation of the specific attributes occurs with `(?!text|xmlUrl)`, which says don't match those characters. Also, note that the word boundary `\b` at the beginning ensures that we're matching the full attribute name of `text` and not the possibility of other attributes with the same termination such as `subtext`.

```
\b((?!text|xmlUrl)\w+)="[^"]*"
```

#### Method 2

This method only works with regex flavours that allow backreferences. Apparently JGsoft applications, Delphi, Perl, Python, Ruby, PHP, R, Boost, and Tcl support single-digit backreferences. Double-digit backreferences are supported by JGsoft applications, Delphi, Python, and Boost. Information according [this article about numbered backreferences from Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/1vjFdX/4)

This method uses a backreference to ensure the same closing mark is used at the start and end of the attribute's value and also includes the possibility of whitespace surrounding the `=` symbol. This doesn't allow the possibility for attributes with no delimiter specified (using `xmlUrl=http://softwareengineeringdaily.com/feed/podcast/` may also be valid).

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yLWCdL/2)

```
\b(text|xmlUrl)\s*=\s*(["'])(.*?)\2
```

#### Method 3

This method is the same as **Method 2** but also allows attributes with no delimiters (note that delimiters are now considered to be space characters, thus, it will only match until the next space).

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yLWCdL/3)

```
\b(text|xmlUrl)\s*=\s*(?:(["'])(.*?)\2|(\S*))
```

#### Method 4

While **Method 3** works, some people might complain that the attribute values might either of 2 groups. This can be fixed by either of the following methods.

**Method 4.A**

Branch reset groups are only possible in a few languages, notably JGsoft V2, PCRE 7.2+, PHP, Delphi, R (with PCRE enabled), Boost 1.42+ according to [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)

This also shows the method you would use if backreferences aren't possible and you wanted to match multiple delimiters (`"([^"])"|'([^']*)`)

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yLWCdL/4)

```
\b(text|xmlUrl)\s*=\s*(?|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|(\S*))
```

**Method 4.B**

Duplicate subpatterns are not often supported. See [this Regular-Expresions.info article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) for more information

This method uses the `J` regex flag, which allows duplicate subpattern names (`(?<v>)` is in there twice)

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yLWCdL/5)

```
\b(text|xmlUrl)\s*=\s*(?:(["'])(?<v>.*?)\2|(?<v>\S*))
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
<outline text="Software Engineering Daily" type="rss" xmlUrl="http://softwareengineeringdaily.com/feed/podcast/" htmlUrl="http://softwareengineeringdaily.com" />
```

#### Output

Each line below represents a different group. New matches are separated by two lines.

```
text
Software Engineering Daily

xmlUrl
http://softwareengineeringdaily.com/feed/podcast/
```

---

### Explanation

I'll explain different parts of the regexes used in the **Code** section that way you understand the usage of each of these parts. This is more of a reference to the methods above.

- `"[^"]*"` This is the fastest method possible (to the best of my knowledge) to grabbing anything between two `"` symbols. Note that it **does not** check for escaped backslashes, it will match any non-`"` character between two `"`. Whilst `"(.*?)"` can also be used, it's slightly slower
- `(["'])(.*?)\2` is basically shorthand for `"(.*?)"|'(.*?)'`. You can use any of the following methods to get the same result:

  - `(?:"(.*?)"|'(.*?)')`
  - `(?:"([^"])"|'([^']*)')` <-- slightly faster than line above
- `(?|)` This is a branch reset group. When you place groups inside it like `(?|(x)|(y))` it returns the same group index for both matches. This means that if `x` is captured, it'll get group index of 1, and if `y` is captured, it'll also get a group index of 1.

Comment: Thanks a mil. so if I want to do the opposite, select all the other characters   (for removal) and not select the description ; I should just negate the statement?

Comment: @Tlink I'm not quite sure what you mean by *description*, could you elaborate?

Comment: I mean the title (text) for the podcast link above

Comment: Just add whichever attributes you want to match in the first group. So if you didn't want to match `text`, you would simply remove it from the group as such: `\b(xmlUrl)="[^"]*"`

Comment: Sorry I didn't phrase that question correctly, I was meaning to say if I wanted to reverse the lookup above.  reverse as in running a new regex, but this time selecting everthing I've left in the above example and leaving the parts I selected.

Comment: @Tlink I've added more information under method 1 with what I believe is what you're asking (according to you last comment ^)

Answer (score 1):

For *simple* `HTML` strings you might get along with

```
Url=(['"])(.+?)\1
```

Here, take group `$2`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/s4wrKD/1/).
Obligatory: consider using a parser instead (see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)).